# PHP Custom Session Management Class

Tags: php, session, static, try-catch

So I have a class I'm working on to manage PHP sessions, here's the class:

```
class SessionManagement {
    public static function sessionStarted() {
        if(session_id() == '') {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public static function sessionExists($session) {
        if(sessionStarted() == false) {
            session_start();
        }
        if(isset($_SESSION[$session])) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static function setSession($session, $value) {
        if(sessionStarted() != true) {
            session_start();
        }
        $_SESSION[$session] = $value;
        if(sessionExists($session) == false) {
            throw new Exception('Unable to Create Session');
        }
    }
    public static function getSession($session) {
        if(isset($_SESSION[$session])) {
            return $_SESSION[$session];
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Session Does Not Exist');
        }
    }
}
```

Now trying this...

```
try {
    SessionManagement::setSession('Foo', 'Bar');

    echo SessionManagement::sessionStarted();
    echo SessionManagement::getSession('Foo');
    echo SessionManagement::sessionExists('Foo');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

...produces no output...I'm not sure where we're breaking here...any helpful eyes is greatly appreciated...

Comment: All of your methods are static, but you're calling them in object context.

Comment: Also the `sessionStarted()` function doesn't exists. You need `$this->sessionStarted()` or `static::sessionStarted()`.

Comment: Updated....still no output.

Comment: Anybody? I'm glazed over here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike other OO languages, like C++, in your class PHP needs to know that the static methods called are from *this* object. For an instantiated class, that would be through `$this`, and in your case, static methods, this is done via `self`:

```
class SessionManagement {
    public static function sessionStarted() {
        if(session_id() == '') {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public static function sessionExists($session) {
        if(self::sessionStarted() == false) {
            session_start();
        }
        if(isset($_SESSION[$session])) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static function setSession($session, $value) {
        if(self::sessionStarted() != true) {
            session_start();
        }
        $_SESSION[$session] = $value;
        if(self::sessionExists($session) == false) {
            throw new Exception('Unable to Create Session');
        }
    }
    public static function getSession($session) {
        if(isset($_SESSION[$session])) {
            return $_SESSION[$session];
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Session Does Not Exist');
        }
    }
}
```

Prepending `self::` to all internal calls to the `SessionManagement` static methods should solve your problem.

Comment: Correct way in modern php is `static::`, it's functionally almost the same with the difference that when you extend the class `static::overwritten_method` will call the new method, while `self::overwritten_method` will still invoke the method from the current class the code is in. In cases where you think `self::` makes sense you might wish to just use private visibility on the method instead.